# Como contar quantas vezes um item se repete em um Array com tamanho desconhecido?

Tags: java, array

Como contar quantas vezes um item aparece em um Array na qual não sei o tamanho? O array foi criado a partir de um .CSV.

Comment: Considerou usar um loop `for(Object object : csv)` ao invés e algo `for(int i = 0; i < csv.length; i++)`?

Comment: Se você tem um array então você pode obter o seu tamanho - é só acessar a propriedade `length` do array - independente de como o array foi criado.

Comment: @user2296455 se a resposta tiver solucionado sua dúvida avise, se não avise também. :)

Answer (score 6):

Acho que você pode fazer assim, criar um método e passar por parâmetro o Array e o Item a ser verificado, se for uma Array de String por exemplo:

```
public int contarRepeticoes(String[] array, String valor) {

    int contador = 0;

    if(array!=null) {
        for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++) {
             if(array[i]!=null) {
                 if(array[i].equals(valor)) {
                      contador++;
                 }
             }
        }
    } else {
            System.out.println("Vetor nulo");
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Acho que alguma coisa parecida com isso funciona, to sem IDE aqui pra testar.

Answer (score 5):

O código abaixo serve para qualquer tipo de dado de entrada (String, int, double etc):

```
public static int contaArray(ArrayList<Object> array, Object valorProcurado){
    int contador = 0;
    if (array != null){
        for (Object item : array){
            if (item != null && item.equals(valorProcurado)){
                contador++;
            }
        }
    }
    return contador;
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, não sabia isso! Mas mesmo se ele passar um array normal vai funcionar?

Comment: @JoãoNeto Do jeito que está você não pode passar um array normal, mas esse "for" especial também funciona com arrays, portanto bastaria alterar a assinatura do método sem modificar o conteúdo.

Comment: Entendi @utluiz. Valeu!